# Default DateTime Parameter in EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, detailsview

I have a ASP.Net DetailsView, bound to an EntityDataSource control.
My EntitySet has a DateTime Property that I want to set to a **default value of DateTime.Now**
I don't want to display this property on the DetailsView.
I figure I could use an InsertParameter in my EntityDataSource, but don't know the syntax, or whether this is possible:

```
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" DefaultValue="" />
        </InsertParameters>
```

Am I taking the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't look like it's possible to do this in HTML, but you can do it easy in code behind.
Simply attach an Inserting event handler to your entity data source, and then set the DateTime parameter to the defaults you require:

```
    protected void edsNewsItem_Inserting(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        var newsItem = e.Entity as NewsItem;
        if (newsItem != null)
        {
            newsItem.Date = DateTime.Now;
            newsItem.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```